# Replace &Type with &Wrapper<Type>

Tags: rust

I have a reference to a value and I would like to replace it with a reference to a *wrapper* struct wrapping the value.

Example:

```
struct Wrapper<T>(T);

let num = 123;
let x: &i32 = &num;
let wrapped: &Wrapper<i32> = .. // some conversion
```

Is this possible? (a *safe* solution is preferred, but not necessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to make your example code work:

```
let wrapped: &Wrapper<i32> = &Wrapper(*x);    // type annotation optional
```

Coming from C++, you might think this is crazily unsafe, because we take a reference to a temporary (the expression on the left hand side). But in situations like this, Rust just saves the result of this temporary expression on the stack. The above code is equivalent to:

```
let hidden = Wrapper(*x);
let wrapped: &Wrapper = &hidden;
```

So far so good, but a problem arises when we want to return this reference. For example:

```
fn wrap<T>(t: &T) -> &Wrapped<T> {
    &Wrapped(*t)
}
```

We have two problems here. First, we can't move out of `t` (it's only borrowed; it only worked in the code above because `i32` is `Copy`) and second, we can't return a reference to a local variable (the `hidden` one that is created for us).

---

To solve this, you could use the `unsafe` function [`std::mem::transmute()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html). This just interprets any type as another any other type.

But wait! `unsafe {}` means "compiler, trust me on this!", but should we trust ourselves? We as a programmer would have to guarantee that `Wrapped<T>` and `T` have the exact same data layout. So: is that the case?

It's probably true on most platforms, but I very much doubt we can guarantee this! Rust doesn't seem to promise a lot when it comes to data layout of structs (and unit structs). It may reorder fields (not important in this case) and may add padding. There is more information on this in the [repr(Rust) chapter of the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html).

---

**To summarize**: a function like `wrap()` *can't* be safely implemented. As a consequence, APIs containing functions like that should be avoided.

Comment: The question is, when is the function `wrap` sound and under what conditions? We don't have any documented guarantee.

Comment: @bluss I added more information on that issue. It seems like it's really unsafe and it shouldn't be used, thus I removed the exact code, too. I'm sorry for offering `unsafe` solutions in my SO answers. I usually don't do that, but I wrote this answer like 10 minutes after waking up ^_^

Comment: @bluss I think I have made some assumptions about memory layout in a few applications, (e.g. `transmute((u32, u32)) :: u64` which makes an unsafe assumption about the layout of `(,)`). Is there a tracking issue for how this sort of thing (enforcing layout guarantees) will be solved in a future Rust?

Comment: first of all, absolutely don't do that, you have a perfectly fine type in `[u32; 2]` that you can use for a pair of u32 laid out without padding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any conversions; you can achieve this in the following manner:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Wrapper(i32);

let num = 123; // the value
let x = &num; // the reference to the value
let wrapped: Wrapper = Wrapper(*x); // now you can refer to &wrapped

println!("{:?}", wrapped);
```